# How can I simplify code that modifies Window Styles using SetWindowLong & GetWindowLong?

Tags: windows, styles, redraw, setwindowlong

I'm writing some wrapper functions and classes for the Windows API. A common occurrence I'm starting to come across is modifying Windows Styles.

The following is some example code that my adjusts a TextBox's Text Alignment based on the parameter ALIGNMENT enum. After much testing it seems I must remove the 2 alternative Alignment styles or it will conflict. Then SetWindowPos(..SWP_FRAMECHANGED) doesn't work either, so I replaced it with InvalidateRect() and UpdateWindow() to force the TextBox to be repainted after the style is updated.

I'd like some feedback if there is a simpler way of doing this. I feel like I'm overlooking something. Thanks! :)

```
enum ALIGNMENT
{
    Left,
    Right,
    Center
};

void TextBox::Alignment(ALIGNMENT Alignment)
{
    switch (Alignment)
    {
        case ALIGNMENT::Left:
            SetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, (GetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~ES_CENTER & ~ES_RIGHT) | ES_LEFT);
        break;
        case ALIGNMENT::Center:
            SetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, (GetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~ES_LEFT & ~ES_RIGHT) | ES_CENTER);
        break;
        case ALIGNMENT::Right:
            SetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, (GetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~ES_LEFT & ~ES_CENTER) | ES_RIGHT);
        break;
    }

    InvalidateRect(m_hWnd, NULL, true);
    UpdateWindow(m_hWnd);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WinUser.h:

```
#define ES_LEFT             0x0000L
#define ES_CENTER           0x0001L
#define ES_RIGHT            0x0002L
```

so you can do

```
void TextBox::Alignment(ALIGNMENT Alignment)
{
    int style = ES_LEFT; // default to left alignment
    switch (Alignment)
    {
        case ALIGNMENT::Center:
            style = ES_CENTER;
            break;
        case ALIGNMENT::Right:
            style = ES_RIGHT;
            break;
    }

    SetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLongPtr(m_hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~(ES_CENTER|ES_RIGHT) | style);
    InvalidateRect(m_hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
    UpdateWindow(m_hWnd);
};
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. :)
I'll lookout for NULL value #defines more often. I also changed to TRUE from true. Nice pickup.